# I found that lambda functions in C++ can bypass const restrictions, is it a bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am testing my implementation of lazy evaluation. To achieve this, I passed a lambda function as an argument to the member constructor, which will be executed only when the first evaluation occurs. However, I noticed that the lambda function has access to the class member variables through the captured variable, and I am able to modify them inside the lambda function.

My test function with const restrictions as following:

```cpp
void print_root(const Foo& f) {
    for(auto i:iota(0,10)) std::cout << f.root() << std::endl;
}
```

The implementation is as following

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Lazy {
private:
    std::function<T()> get_value;
    mutable std::mutex mutex;
    mutable bool evaluated = false;
    mutable T value;
public:
    Lazy(std::function<T()> f) : get_value(f) {}
    const T& operator()() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        if(!evaluated) {
            value = get_value();
            evaluated = true;
        }
        return value;
    }
};

struct Foo {
private:
    double x;
public:
    Lazy<double> root;
    Foo(double _x) : x(_x), root(
        [this]()->double { 
            double a = x/2;
            std::cout << "Calculating root of " << x << std::endl;
            for(auto i:iota(0, 1000000000)) a = (a + x/a) / 2;
            x = 3; //try to modify this-> x
            return a;
        }
    ) {}
};
```

Then g++ compiler do not report any error.

Comment: [You don't really need a lambda](https://godbolt.org/z/7PdTv1hqG).

Comment: `operator()()` is almost certainly broken. `value` shouldn't be `static`, it should immediately `return get_value();`  and it should have return type either `auto` or `decltype(auto)`. Otherwise it is broken if used with the same `T` multiple times in the program. In any case, your `Lazy` is just `std::function<T()>`. You can use that directly instead (`template<typename T> using Lazy = std::function<T()>;`)

Comment: If you capture `[this]`, **the pointer** `this` will be const.  If you capture `[*this]`, the object this points to will be const.  Your code makes the pointer const, which doesn't make the object pointed to const.

Comment: Why exactly do you expect not to be able to modify the members in the lambda? (Asking because all of the stuff you show except for the lambda itself seems to be irrelevant if your confusion is simply regarding the meaning of capturing `this`.)

Comment: By default `const` only implies constness of the current object. So if the object has a pointer/reference to another object, one can call non-const operations on it, but one cannot change the pointer itself. Here lambda uses `this` but doesn't change its address (which isn't possible to begin with...).

Comment: @user17732522 because operator `()` of lambda is const by default. Same with opperator `()` of the `std::function` as well as of `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: @ALX23z Yes, but if that is the question, why show `Lazy` at all in the question instead of simply demonstrating that the lambda in `Foo` can be called? What about `Lazy` does OP expect to be relevant to whether or not the lambda can modify members of the captured `Foo` instance?

Comment: Btw. the whole approach is also broken without a custom copy constructor and assignment operator on `Foo`. When `Foo` is copied, then the new copy's `root` will still store a lambda referring to the original `Foo` object, not the new one. Storing a pointer/reference (in)to `this` inside `this` itself is not a good idea in general for that reason.

Comment: @user17732522 Thak you, it is a mistake, I use static because I hope it can work correctly in multithreaded mode without using locks. But that is not my question.

Comment: @user17732522 I meet the question when I am testing implementation of lazy evaluation and I think the code is not complex, which can be as an example. I think root() should be a const member function, since the root is actually a property and evaluating it does not modify the instance. However, x is the field and it should not be modified.

Comment: @葛盈泽 `root` is a const **variable**, holding a const pointer.  A const pointer is not the same as a pointer to a const object.

Comment: @葛盈泽 `root` is not a function at all. It is just a data member of type `Lazy<double>` and not `const`-qualified. But that is irrelevant to whether or not the lambda can access members of the captured `this`. That's only a matter of whether or not `this` is a pointer-to-`const` or not and in the default member initializer it is not. `this` has type `Foo*`, not `const Foo*`, so it can be used to write to members. That's true if you store `Foo*` directly as a member of a class as well. Whether or not a member function is `const` is then irrelevant to accessing members through the `Foo*` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing `this` behaves essentially as if you had captured the pointer value of `this` with the same type and each member access in the lambda body is rewritten to access through that captured pointer.

In the default member initializer of `root`, the type of `this` is `Foo*`, not `const Foo*`. So the captured `this` will also be non-`const`. Whether or not the `operator()` of the lambda is then `const`-qualified doesn't matter. If you have a pointer of type `Foo* const`, then dereferencing it still gives you a `Foo` lvalue, not a `const Foo` lvalue.

This is exactly the same as storing a pointer as a class member:

```
struct Foo {
    int a = 0;

    Foo* x = this;

    void f() const {
        this->a++; // error, `this` is prvalue of type `const Foo*`
                   // so `*this` is lvalue of type `const Foo`
        x->a++;    // ok, `x` is lvalue of type `Foo* const`,
                   // after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of type `Foo*`
                   // so `*x` is lvalue of type `Foo`
    }
};
```

(Please also consider the comments I and others made under the question regarding general issues with the design and use of your `Lazy`.)